# Using helper in controller in Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm confused by the rails documentation that I'm reading [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html).  In particular, this sentence:

> By default, each controller will include all helpers. These helpers
>   are only accessible on the controller through `.helpers`

What is this `.helpers` that it is referring to? I have a helper defined in `app/helpers/areas_helper.rb`:

```
module AreasHelper
  def my_helper
    puts "Test from helper"
  end
end
```

I would like to use this helper in `app/controllers/locations_controller.rb`:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    helpers.my_helper
  end
end
```

However, I get a method undefined error. How is this `.helpers` supposed to be used?

I know there are other ways to get access to helpers in controllers, but I'm specifically asking about this piece of documentation and what it's trying to say.

Comment: I believe the reference to `.helpers` is the inbuilt Rails helpers, such as `redirect_to` etc

Comment: But what does that mean. Where does `.helpers` come into play when using a built in Rails helper like `redirect_to`?

Comment: Tbh I don't know. I am reading up on it. My answer is valid, that's how we use custom helpers in our controllers - as for `.helpers` I am looking at it

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for an answer or explanation specifically for that part of the documentation if possible.

Comment: As far as I understood Helpers are often used in your VIEW. Eg, having your own complex 'link_to' version. This way you can still keep complex logic out of the view and just call the method from it.

Answer (score 9):

You're meant to include the helper class in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/locations_controller.rb
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
   include AreasHelper

   def show
      my_helper
   end
end
```

Comment: If several helpers needed, they can be separate by commas - ```include AreasHelper, AnotherHelper```

Answer (score 5):

This feature was introduced in Rails 5 with following PR
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24866

So, we can use this feature from Rails 5 and onwards and not in Rails 4.x.